# Performing Count out of the case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, count, case

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cst_recno as 'MemID',
 evt_code as 'MeetingID',
 etp_code as 'Event Type',
 evt_start_date as 'Event Start Date',
case 
       when net_ivd_amount_cp=0 
       then 'Comp' 
       else 'Paid' 
end as 'P/C'
FROM 
ev_registrant  
join ev_event on evt_key=reg_evt_key
LEFT JOIN ev_event_type ON evt_etp_key = etp_key 
LEFT JOIN ev_event_location  ON evl_evt_key = evt_key 
LEFT JOIN ev_location  ON evl_loc_key = loc_key 
LEFT join ac_invoice_detail on reg_ivd_key=ivd_key
LEFT join vw_ac_invoice_detail on net_ivd_key=ivd_key
JOIN co_customer ON reg_cst_key=cst_key and cst_delete_flag=0 and reg_delete_flag=0 
WHERE reg_cancel_date is NULL AND reg_delete_flag = 0 and reg_attendance_flag=1
and evt_start_date >='7/1/2017' and evt_title = 'uli europe conference 2018'
order by cst_recno
```

giving me below output:

```
MemID   MeetingID   Event Type  Event Start Date      P/C      
14191   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Paid  
16544   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Comp  
16592   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Paid
17415   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Comp  
18531   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Paid  
19922   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Comp  
21207   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Paid
22832   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Comp  
26346   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Comp  
27607   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Paid  
33674   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Paid
```

I would like to add two columns that would count distinct values the P/C column and than assigned that count to the entire column so that my desired output would look like this:

```
MemID   MeetingID   Event Type  Event Start Date      P/C    Paid  Comp
14191   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Paid   6     5
16544   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Comp   6     5
16592   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Paid   6     5
17415   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Comp   6     5
18531   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Paid   6     5
19922   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Comp   6     5
21207   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Paid   6     5
22832   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Comp   6     5
26346   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Comp   6     5
27607   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Paid   6     5
33674   33100418    Conference  2018-01-30 00:00:00   Paid   6     5
```

Comment: Do you know what a subquery is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a sub-query:

```
SELECT
  *
  ,(SELECT COUNT([P/C]) FROM tbl WHERE [P/C] = 'Paid') AS Paid
  ,(SELECT COUNT([P/C]) FROM tbl WHERE [P/C] = 'Comp') AS Comp
 FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT cst_recno as 'MemID',
     evt_code as 'MeetingID',
     etp_code as 'Event Type',
     evt_start_date as 'Event Start Date',
    case 
           when net_ivd_amount_cp=0 
           then 'Comp' 
           else 'Paid' 
    end as 'P/C'
    FROM 
    ev_registrant  
    join ev_event on evt_key=reg_evt_key
    LEFT JOIN ev_event_type ON evt_etp_key = etp_key 
    LEFT JOIN ev_event_location  ON evl_evt_key = evt_key 
    LEFT JOIN ev_location  ON evl_loc_key = loc_key 
    LEFT join ac_invoice_detail on reg_ivd_key=ivd_key
    LEFT join vw_ac_invoice_detail on net_ivd_key=ivd_key
    JOIN co_customer ON reg_cst_key=cst_key and cst_delete_flag=0 and reg_delete_flag=0 
    WHERE reg_cancel_date is NULL AND reg_delete_flag = 0 and reg_attendance_flag=1
    and evt_start_date >='7/1/2017' and evt_title = 'uli europe conference 2018'
    ) tbl
order by MemID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select . . .,
       sum(case when net_ivd_amount_cp = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by MeetingID) as comp,
       sum(case when net_ivd_amount_cp <> 0 or net_ivd_amount_cp is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by MeetingID) as paid
```

I am suspicious of the `select distinct`.  I don't see why this would be needed for this query.  Under some circumstances, the window functions will not product the results you expect with the `select distinct`.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `cte` like below might help you:

```
;with cte (MemID,MeetingID,EventType,EventStartDate,PC) as
(
   SELECT DISTINCT cst_recno as 'MemID',
   evt_code as 'MeetingID',
   etp_code as 'EventType',
   evt_start_date as 'EventStartDate',
   case 
       when net_ivd_amount_cp=0 
       then 'Comp' 
       else 'Paid' 
   end as 'PC'
   FROM 
   ev_registrant  
   join ev_event on evt_key=reg_evt_key
   LEFT JOIN ev_event_type ON evt_etp_key = etp_key 
   LEFT JOIN ev_event_location  ON evl_evt_key = evt_key 
   LEFT JOIN ev_location  ON evl_loc_key = loc_key 
   LEFT join ac_invoice_detail on reg_ivd_key=ivd_key
   LEFT join vw_ac_invoice_detail on net_ivd_key=ivd_key
   JOIN co_customer ON reg_cst_key=cst_key and cst_delete_flag=0 and reg_delete_flag=0 
   WHERE reg_cancel_date is NULL AND reg_delete_flag = 0 and reg_attendance_flag=1
   and evt_start_date >='7/1/2017' and evt_title = 'uli europe conference 2018'
   order by cst_recno
)
select *,
       (select count(*) from cte where PC = 'Paid') as Paid,
       (select count(*) from cte where PC = 'Comp') as Comp
from cte
```

Comment: You are very welcome. I appreciate if you select the answer as the correct one by clicking the tick on the left if it was helpful to you. Regards. @klima

Comment: Quick follow up, if I add one more evt_title in ('uli europe conference 2018','test') and would like to make sure that it counts Comp and Paid per that event and not total. What would be your approach to accomplish that? @Eray Balkanli

Comment: You can create another cte for another title, or remove evt_title filter in your where clause (inside cte) and use "group by" clause at the very end. Like: .....select title,count(*) from cte where PC='Paid' group by title..... It is healthier to ask it as a different question @klima